# How do I rotate all graphics in form without causing MouseArgs to go haywire

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

Lately I found out how to rotate images and I already have problem.
Here is piece of code that I have problem with but you probably don't need to look at it anyway...

```
Graphics g = e.Graphics;
g.TranslateTransform((float)Width / 2, (float)Height / 2);
g.RotateTransform(myAngle);

Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(32, 1, 1, 1));
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 128 , 128, 128), 3);

g.FillRectangle(brush, nX, nY, snX - nX, snY - nY);
g.DrawRectangle(pen, nX, nY, snX - nX, snY - nY);
```

variables X , sX , snX, Y , sY, snY are coordinates of mouse in specific moments and are calculated mostly in `Form1_MouseMove` and I can't show what's in there.

How can I make these variables also change no matter what `myAngle` is?

Comment: You could transform your mouse coords by the inverted transformation: `var matrix = g.Transform; matrix.Invert(); matrix.TransformPoints(mousecoords)` This will transform your mouse coords to the coords of the rotated bitmap.

Comment: Reset the translate after the rotate! : `g.TranslateTransform((float)Width / 2, (float)Height / 2);
g.RotateTransform(myAngle); g.TranslateTransform(-(float)Width / 2, -(float)Height / 2);` But: You really need to understand where the rotation center is supposed to be! Here it is the form center for everything you draw.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen thank you, it was just what i needed

Comment: @TaW that also works perfectly fine and i finally learnt what translate form does. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made an example, how to draw on a rotated bitmap: *(using a picturebox/bitmap/trackbar)*

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Bitmap _bitmap;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
    }

    private void TransformGraphics(Graphics g)
    {
        g.ResetTransform();
        g.TranslateTransform(_bitmap.Width / 2, _bitmap.Height / 2);
        g.RotateTransform(trackBar1.Value);
        g.TranslateTransform(-_bitmap.Width / 2, -_bitmap.Height / 2);
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        TransformGraphics(e.Graphics);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(_bitmap, new Point());
    }

    private Point? _previousPoint;

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        _previousPoint = e.Location;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        _previousPoint = null;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_previousPoint.HasValue)
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(_bitmap))
            {
                TransformGraphics(g);
                var matrix = g.Transform;
                matrix.Invert();


                var points = new[] { _previousPoint.Value, e.Location };

                matrix.TransformPoints(points);

                g.ResetTransform();
                g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, points[0], points[1]);
                pictureBox1.Invalidate();

                _previousPoint = e.Location;
            }
        }
    }

    private void trackBar1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

[image: RotatedDraw]

---

You can add another trackbar for scaling.